# Nginx laravel configuration

Tags: linux, laravel, nginx

I am currently developing a laravel application, on a nginx webserver, I have always accessed my projects by editing /etc/hosts and adding an entry for the name of the project then adding a server block with server name in default file in nginx, so if I have a project called "Missouri", I would call it like this :

> http://missouri/

I would like now to change this is a bit, and to use my IP Address, or my localhost to be before the project name, like this :

> http://localhost/missouri/

I have searched a lot, found a lot of different combinations, but none was efficient, this is the configuration block for the general server configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ^~  /Missouri {
    alias /var/www/html/Missouri/public;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /Missouri/index.php?$query_string;

         location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
         }

    }
}
```

If I use the previous configuration and call localhost/Missouri I get a File not found. white page error, however if I use the following code and call Missouri/ it works :

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name missouri;

root /var/www/html/Missouri/public;
index index.php index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a DevOps but I think that you can write regex in your nginx server block, so "localhost/foo" will be an alias for "localhost/foo/public". By doing that you don't need to add block for every website.

On the other hand, about your question, I'd recommend you to use "root" instead of "alias". Here is an example code:

```
location /Missouri {
       root /var/www/html/Missouri/public;

       index index.php index.html;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include fastcgi_params;
       }
}
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Unfortunately it did not work for me.